# Conversations cannot log in to ejabberd - error in stream

Tags: ejabberd

The *ejabberd* server I'm configuring has the following configuration for certfiles and for the port 5222.
*Gajim*, *Psi* and *Pidgin* can connect fine.
*Conversations* cannot. There's some stream error.

*ejabberd's* log shows

````
2021-07-15 16:15:01.459 [info] <0.381.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:273 (<0.649.0>) Accepted connection 88.88.88.72:65069 -> 192.168.7.5:5222```
````

For Gajim, besides a line like the one above, it has two more when opening the connection:

```
2021-07-15 16:16:10.465 [info] <0.651.0>@ejabberd_c2s:process_auth_result:268 (tls|<0.651.0>) Accepted c2s SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication for test1@myserver by mnesia backend from 88.88.88.72
2021-07-15 16:16:10.550 [info] <0.651.0>@ejabberd_c2s:bind:442 (tls|<0.651.0>) Opened c2s session for test1@myserver/gajim.W2AAA7JO
```

Part of the *ejabberd's* config file is:

```
certfiles:
  - "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/myserver.pem"
  - "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/myserver.key"
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
    starttls: true
    starttls_required: true
    protocol_options:
        - "no_sslv2"
        - "no_sslv3"
        - "no_tlsv1"
        - "no_tlsv1_1"
    ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
    dhfile:
      "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/c2s_dh2048.pem"
```

I've also tried commenting out the `ciphers` and `no_ssl*`, `no_tls*` but to no avail.

The ejabberd server is running not at the gateway but in a LAN location with port forwarding enabled.

What is wrong between *Conversations* and *ejabberd*?

Answer (score 1):

```
tls: true
starttls: true
```

Those options are mutually exclusive. `starttls` is usually set at port 5222, and `tls` at port 5223.

And looking at the [tls](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/listen-options/#tls) option documentation:

> Enabling this option implicitly disables the starttls option.

So, you enabled `tls` on port 5222, which is a bad idea... together with `starttls`, which is another bad idea.

Simply, set `tls` to false or remove that line.